# How to close AWS connection if there is no such key in the query

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk, aws-sdk

I'm using AWS java SDK to upload file on AWS Management Console's Bucket. However, if there is no such file online at first time when I try to get access to it, my code will catch the exception (NoSuchKey). Then I want to close the connection. The problem is I don't have any reference to close that connection because of the exception(The original reference will be null). Here is my code:

```
    S3Object object = null;
    GetObjectRequest req = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName);

    try{
        logconfig();

        object = s3Client.getObject(req);
                  ...
    catch(AmazonServiceException e){
        if(e.getErrorCode().equals("NoSuchKey"))
```

I was trying to use "object" as a reference to close the connection between my eclipse and Aws, but apparently "object" is null when the exception happened.
Can anyone tell me how to do it? 
Furthermore, because I can't close the connection, my console will have this warning every 60 seconds:

```
8351167 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager  - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
```

Comment: I don't think you need to do any connection handling yourself. That's taken care by library. You just need to call APIs present in `s3client`.

Comment: You should call close() to the object if it implements Closable(). Otherwise resource leak may be happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Java 1.7, you can use [try-with-resouce](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block. The object will be closed automatically when leaving the block.

```
GetObjectRequest req = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName);
try(S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(req)) {
    ...
} catch(AmazonServiceException e) {
    if(e.getErrorCode().equals("NoSuchKey"));
}
```

If you use Java 1.6 or prior version, you need to do it in finally block

```
S3Object object = null;
GetObjectRequest req = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName);
try {
    object = s3Client.getObject(req))
    ...
} catch(AmazonServiceException e) {
    if(e.getErrorCode().equals("NoSuchKey"));
} finally {
    if (object != null) {
        object.close();
    }
}
```