# Getting file size from S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get the file size (content-length) using Amazon S3 JAVA sdk.

```
public Long getObjectSize(AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client, String bucket, String key)
        throws IOException {
    Long size = null;
    S3Object object = null;
    try {
        object = amazonS3Client.getObject(bucket, key);
        size = object.getObjectMetadata().getContentLength();

    } finally {
        if (object != null) {
            //object.close();
            1. This results in 50 calls (connection pool size) post that I start getting connection pool errors. 
            2. If this line is uncommented it takes hell lot of time to make calls.
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

I followed [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233259/how-to-close-aws-connection-if-there-is-no-such-key-in-the-query). But not sure what I am doing wrong here.
Any help on this?

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then update your question to specify exactly what your issue is. Are you getting an error? Are you getting an incorrect file size? You have some comments in your code about calls to `object.close()` taking a long time, but that seems to be a completely different issue from the question about getting an object's file size.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm guessing what your actual question is asking, but I think you can reduce your code and eliminate the need to create an s3Object at all by doing something like:

```
public Long getObjectSize(AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client, String bucket, String key)
        throws IOException {
    return amazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(bucket, key).getContentLength();
}
```

That should remove the need to call `object.close()` which you appear to be having issues with.

Comment: Perhaps, would be better to use getInstanceLenght() instead of getContentLenght(), because if you selectively download a range of the file using setRange(), content length gives you the http content length of the request which in this case would be your range(e.g. for setRange(0,100), getContentLength() will return 100 and not the actual file size)

Answer (score 6):

For v2 of the Amazon S3 Java SDK, try something like this:

```
HeadObjectRequest headObjectRequest =
        HeadObjectRequest.builder()
          .bucket(bucket)
          .key(key)
          .build();
HeadObjectResponse headObjectResponse =
        s3Client.headObject(headObjectRequest);
Long contentLength = headObjectResponse.contentLength();
```

Answer (score 1):

So we have 2 SDKs.

For v1 of the Amazon S3 Java SDK, below

```
client.getObjectMetadata(bucket, key).getContentLength();
```

where client is an instance of `AmazonS3` coming from `import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;` and     `implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.12.353'` gradle dependencies.

For v2 of the Amazon S3 Java SDK, below:

```
return client.headObject(HeadObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(key).build()).contentLength();
```

where client is instance of `S3Client` coming from `import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;` and gradle dependencies `implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.18.35'`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 2.x client version doesn't have `amazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(bucket, key)` method, but there is a different one:

```
        Long size = s3Client.getObjectAttributes(GetObjectAttributesRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .key(objectKey)
            .build()).objectSize();
```

Here `software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client` is used.